# Compare specific column values of two text files - C#

Tags: c#, text-files, string-comparison

I have a case where I need to compare two text files (using C#), an incoming text file, and an existing text file, checking for changes/differences. Both text files have the same layout, 6 columns of the same type of data and column headers. So this is basically a check to see if the contents of the incoming file has any new data compared to the existing.

The `File.ReadAllText` method essentially does what I want, the problem is though, I only want to compare the values in the first two columns of the text files, and disregard the other trailing columns.

The text file layout is like the following:

**Item #|Total**|C3|C4|C5|C6

**123|7**|0|0|0|0

So if either the Item # or Total column have a change in the first file compared to the second, the comparing of the files should stop there, and it should be considered a file change.

What is a simple way to approach this? Many thanks.

Comment: What you tried and where you got struck?

Comment: There is only 1 row in each file?

Comment: Hi @Sriram Sakthivel, I tried to use File.ReadAllText, but I believe there could be the possibility that the other columns (not C1 or C2) could have values changed, and I want any changes in those columns to be disregarded.

Comment: Hi @King King, no, there are multiple rows in each file.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy problem when you use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and LINQ's [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx).

```
bool AnyDifferent(string file1FullText, string file2FullText)
{
    string[] file1Lines = file1FullText.Split('\n');
    string[] file2Lines = file2FullText.Split('\n');
    if (file1Lines.Length != file2Lines.Length)
        return true;
    for (int i = 0; i < file1Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var file1LineSplit = file1Lines[i].Split('|');
        var file2LineSplit = file2Lines[i].Split('|');
        if (!file1LineSplit.Take(2).SequenceEqual(file2LineSplit.Take(2)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edit** or using `File.ReadLines` for improved performance (you don't have to read the whole files in before you start comparing them):

```
bool AnyDifferent(string file1Path, string file2Path)
{
    using (var file1Enumerator = File.ReadLines(file1Path).GetEnumerator())
    using (var file2Enumerator = File.ReadLines(file2Path).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool result1 = file1Enumerator.MoveNext();
            bool result2 = file2Enumerator.MoveNext();
            if (result1 != result2)
                return true;
            else if (!result1 && !result2)
                return false;
            var file1LineSplit = file1Enumerator.Current.Split('|');
            var file2LineSplit = file2Enumerator.Current.Split('|');
            if (!file1LineSplit.Take(2).SequenceEqual(file2LineSplit.Take(2)))
               return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `File.ReadLines` on one file instead, then you don't need to read both files into memory first even if the `Length` or the first line is already different.

Comment: @TimSchmelter now that you mention it, why not use `File.ReadLines` on both files?

Comment: Because you need to compare both lines with each other and if you use `ReadLines` on both you always need to enumerate all lines to find the correct index. You can use `foreach` on the deferred lines and the indexer on the array. **Edit** Even more important: you cannot materialze or enumerate `ReadLines` multiple time since the underlying reader is disposed after the first usage.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can use the enumerators manually to step through the two enumerables together. I've added an example of this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually, I think it'd be best (out of options so far) to use the `SequenceEqual` overload that takes an equality comparer that compares the first two items: you get lazy-loaded files, *and* clear logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class for each Item :

```
class Item
{
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

then use a list and compare the data

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines("filepath"))
{
    Item item = new Item
    {
         ItemNumber = Convert.ToInt32(line.Split('|')[0]),
         Total = Convert.ToInt32(line.Split('|')[1])
    };
}
```

then you have a solid structure to compare them with